# How to provide Download Link to Image (JPG) from mongoDB through nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I Have stored Image in MongoDB (Buffer)
now I want to use this image in my react native app
by url like this

e.g http://localhost:8080/fullImg.jpeg

How can I Do this ?

here is my MongoDB Schema

```
const listingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  image:{
      fullImg: { imgBuffer: Buffer, contentType: String },
    },
  price: Number,
})

const Listing = new mongoose.model("Listing", listingSchema);
```

currently Im sending this Buffer to app and
converting it to base64

if posible tell best way to store and retrive the image from mongo db

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to upload image to some storage (Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage...) and then store the `url` of the uploaded image to `MongoDB`. After you fetch data from `MongoDB`, just set `src` property of `img` tag to be `url` of the uploaded image.

If you want to go with your approach of storing Buffer in the MongoDB, you can display the `base64` data in `HTML` like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{your_base64_data}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I provide URL like this http://localhost:8080/fullImg.jpeg ???